# What are the list of valid RMI port?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to validate user's input of RMI host port. I know 1099 is the default RMI port but since the user is able to define which port to use, i need to validate the range of port he input too.. is there a recommended range of ports?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'user', a client system?

Answer (score 1):

Port 49152–65535 are available for any purpose. Ports below this might be used for another purpose. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: wow that is a big range of numbers. do you think is recommend to limit only to 49152-65535

Comment: I would use anything above 1024, but this is a recommended range.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you could use *any* unused port (even thouse below 1024), as long as they're not actually being used for something else on the target systems, right?  For example, port 80 is used for HTTP traffic but there's no reason you couldn't run RMI on port 80 as long as the server and client agree on it.  Right?

Comment: In theory, you can use any port above 0. However port 1 to 1023 can only used with privileges on UNIX systems. e.g. root.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need this *for?* And why is a 'user' inputting a port number in the first place? The only port number an RMI client program needs to know about is 1099, and why the user is getting involved in that is a mystery to me.

Comment: is actually for SCJD Exam ;) when setting up the server.. you need to allow the "expert" user to select the DB, port no. and provide magic cookie.

Comment: @seesee the *DB* port, not the RMI port surely?